# Analog signal driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, analog

I'm trying to create a driver for an analog signal. The signal will be an analog signal from the DAC that will be converted from 0-3V3 to 0-1V. I want to switch this signal on and off using a digital port of my microcontroller but when I calculate this schematic there will always be a small voltage leak due to the Rds(on). How can I prevent this leak current? The duration of the pulse form the microcontroller will be about 300 us or smaller with a frequency of 100 Hz or lower. The signal may be less then 0 V when the MOSFET is conducting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feauyy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's the output voltage of your MCU? Is there any reason you have the LEDs set up the way you do? Also what's the purpose of that 1ohm resistor on the bottom right?

Comment: @SimeonR The MCU is 0-3V3. The 1 ohm resistor with the op-amp and MOSFET is a constant current source. The MOSFET will conduct till the - input is higher then the + input. So basically slowly increasing and decreasing its conductivity to create a constant current based on the + input and - feedback voltage.

Comment: Use that first FET as a series switch (the Ron will cause errors); when off, there will be only leakage currents.

Comment: This will not work.  Pls define Pulse width vs Vdac @ 100Hz  10ns to 300us max?  at what current?

Comment: OA does not have enough slew rate